# Check Flutter / Dart dependencies for known vulnerabilities?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, flutter-dependencies

Is there a possibility to check Flutter/Dart dependencies for known vulnerabilities? An example how it is done for other languages can be seen here: https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/

Answer (score 0):

Dependency checker is good but due to open source it has limitations.
You can try for tools which ar commercial such as Snyk or blackDuck. I was thinking of writing a tool for mobile specifically. ping me and maybe we can work on it

Comment: Limitations in what sense?

Comment: Open source does not have much paying sources so it difficult to find a lot of people who would be willing to make it work for every language out there and also updating and maintaining whenever a new framework is out or new language is out